# Monitoring Windows logon/logoff activities of users in C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm developing a C++ windows application to monitor logon and logoff session activities in real-time.
It should have the followings:

1. Account Name
2. User
3. Account Domain
4. Logon ID
5. Audit success/failure
6. Logged on Time/Date
7. Session time period

It should alert if failure logon attempts or unusual activities occur.
I want to know how to read event logs (say for example only the critical level events in security event logs) using C++. 
I can get these information from windows event viewer. Is there any good way to do this in C++ using windows native APIs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is already a service that you probalby have [service control handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683241(v=vs.85).aspx) already. If you make it register for and handle `SERVICE_CONTROL_SESSIONCHANGE` that could be your fist step.

Then `WTSQuerySessionInformation` will give you most of the information you need.

Re audit, you might want ot post a separate question (or maybe google?) on how to read event log.

Comment: Edited the question. Please look at now.

Comment: It is a different question now. Does [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385650(v=vs.85).aspx) help?

Comment: I have looked into that. There we only query events according to the event ID and publisher name. I want to get all the events by its levels. For example all the critical error level events from Security logs, warning level events from Application logs, etc.